# Why char* Name = "string"; is not working in C++?

Tags: c++

When I write a function like below and use it in `main()`, it doesn't work.

Why does this happen? (I am a beginner).

```cpp
void addBst(char *name, char *num);

int main(void)
{
    addBst("a", "b");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Literal strings in C++ are really *constant* arrays of characters. And as mentioned, since the C++11 standard you must use `const char*` pointers for them.

Comment: to declare a char you need to use single quotes.

Comment: @MohsanAli Sure, but there's no single `char` in play here.

Comment: BTW please don't tag programming questions with the editor you used unless that has any relevance to the question (which it clearly doesn't in this case). Also mentioned in the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio): *"DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio."*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, a string literal is a `const char[N]` array, where `N` is the length of the string, *including* the null terminator.

Since C++11, it is illegal to assign a string literal to a non-const `char*` pointer, as your code is doing. You need to use a `const char*` pointer instead, eg:

```cpp
void addBst(const char *name, const char *num);
```